# Find out whether ActionScript Function has varargs / optional arguments using reflection?

Tags: apache-flex, reflection, actionscript, variadic-functions, optional-arguments

Given an ActionScript Function object, is there any way to determine whether that function has one or more optional parameters, or vararg parameters?  The `length` property seems to return the minimum number of arguments accepted:

```
function vararg(a:*, b:*, ...rest):void {}
function optional(a:*, b:* = null, c:* = null):void {}

trace(vararg.length);   // 2
trace(optional.length); // 1
```

I've tried reflecting over the function properties:

```
for (var name:String in optional) {
  trace(name + ": " + optional[name];
}
```

However this did not output anything at all.

Does anyone know how to discover this information through reflection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I can get you a little bit closer, but not all the way.

If you call `describeType` on the object that has the function AND those functions are public, you will get more information about the functions:

```
var description:XML = describeType(this);
var testFunction:* = description.method.(@name == "optional")[0];

trace(testFunction);
```

This will give you useful output:

```
<method name="optional" declaredBy="MyClass" returnType="void">
  <parameter index="1" type="*" optional="false"/>
  <parameter index="2" type="*" optional="true"/>
  <parameter index="3" type="*" optional="true"/>
  <metadata name="__go_to_definition_help">
    <arg key="file" value="/path/to/MyClass.mxml"/>
    <arg key="pos" value="222"/>
  </metadata>
</method>
```

It also won't tell you about the `...rest` varargs.  So, there are two caveats: they must be public AND you don't get varargs... but you do get a lot more information...

I am not sure you will be able to get any more information than this.

I've always thought `describeType` needs to be able to reflect on private stuff as well... but alas.

Comment: Agreed, Flex's reflection support is a tad squirrelly.  I was hoping for a more encouraging answer than this.  Ah well.

Comment: My problem is that by the time I get the Function object, I have no way to find out what class it's from.  It could be an anonymous function for all I know.  So it looks like I'm out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-1472 is the bug to add varargs to describeType. It's got a priority of "none", which doesn't give much hope that this will be fixed. Maybe voting it up will help though.

Comment: I don't think Adobe puts much weight on the votes.  Flash Builder on Linux was the highest voted issue at the time they announced the halt to the Linux port project.  :-/